# sfttree_ix86_a_50.dll issue during installation of Optisystem software

Tags: dll

I dont know whether dll questions are allowed on stakoverflow or not, please mention in comment if not allowed i will delete this question.

I am trying to install optiwave Optisystem 7.0 software but, as soon as i click on .exe file error message shows,

```
sfttree_ix86_a_50.dll Missing
```

Tried to google the issue but cant get the solution
I used dll-files fixer but, its not fixed
[image]

What show i do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

sfttree_ix86_a_50.dll was missing and I was not able to run the software properly,
I tried dll-file fixer, dll tool etc softwares but none helped
This problem was due to incomplete or corrupted installation.

Steps I performed ro solve the issue:-
 1. I uninstalled the software
 2. Then, reLoaded pendrive with new copy of software
 3. Installed the new copy

Problem solved.